# Would Wanda have stayed reasonable if not informed about America Chavez?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), America Chavez and Doctor Strange landed on Earth-838 and met 838 Mordo. Mordo explained that a
Dreamwalking sorcerer can possess an alternate self in another universe and do irreparable damage.
He warned that they may face the Scarlet Witch:

> America Chavez: Why didn't she do that to begin with?
>
> DOCTOR STRANGE: Because that was **her being reasonable**.

Would Wanda have stayed reasonable if not informed about America Chavez?

Comment: Her being "reasonable" was summoning giant monsters to hunt her down. If she didn't know about America then she wouldn't be doing that either.

Comment: Exactly. That "reasonable" quote comes from the first encounter between Strange and Wanda in the coven... where she uses "reasonable" as her "excuse" to send monsters instead of coming atfer Chavez herself... Again: The answer to the question ist within the same movie...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Signs point towards her eventually being “unreasonable” no matter what.

In the end credits scenes of the *WandaVision* finale we see that Wanda has been restlessly studying [the Darkhold](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Darkhold) - the Book of the Damned. This seems to be feeding her negative traits, making her more determined to get her kids back at all costs.

In that scene, as well as in *Multiverse of Madness* she also has been having recurring dreams of having her kids back. So it seems she’s not coping and moving on but rather growing more and more desperate and determined to do anything to get them back.